# Google cardboard application - small screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I try to create simple VR application using unity + google cardboard sdk.

I install cardboard unity package and import it to unity project. I click update stereo cameras and drag stereo controller to camera. main camera properties are here : 
[image]

My scene has only camera. I run it andorid phone and the result is below.It has small screen. When I use cardboard, I don't see a clear view.

[image]

I install a VR app from play store(SeaWorld VR), it runs properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should disable/delete your 'Main Camera' object and use 'CardboardMain' provided in 'Cardboard/Prefabs/' directory.

Comment: I disable camera. I add Cardboard/Prefabs/CardBoardMain.prefab. Same problem exists when I run this app on android phone.

Answer (score 1):

Under Resolution and Presentation, change “Default Orientation” to “Landscape Left".

New screenshot is :
[image]

Comment: is this the texture of floor u'r using in your app ?

Comment: this is unity default texture such as first image on my question text.

Comment: 1. Does the same project run properly in Unity editor ?
2. Does your test device has Gyroscope ?